# How to make is_arithmetic<myClass>::value to be true?

Tags: c++, templates

The idea is that I have a function that does something arithmetic to the input, so maybe something like:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> 
double mean(const vector<T>& vec)
{
    static_assert(is_arithmetic<T>::value, "Arithmetic not possible on this type");
    //compute mean (average)
}//mean
```

This works great, and computes the mean for all the number types that I put in. But lets say I then create a new class:

```
class foo
{
    // class that has arithmetic operations created
};// foo
```

And in the definition of this class, I defined the needed operators, + and /, so they work with expected inputs. Now I want to use my mean function with my new class, but it obviously won't compile due to the static_assert. So how do I tell the compiler that my new class should satisfy `is_arithmetic<foo>::value` ?

It would be great if when I create the class I could give it a type that satisfies is_arithmetic, but this seems like it might cause a problem with type_traits somehow?

Or would I need to create a new test, that checks to see

```
is_arithmetic<T>::value || type(T,foo)
```

or something like that?

I'd prefer to only have to adapt my class, rather than the function if possible, but I'm curious for a solution.

Comment: You need to write your own trait.

Comment: @T.C. Okay, I thought as much. Is that as simple creating a new `struct` like `is_like_number` and via template specification declaring it true for `foo`?

Nevermind, you answer it below. Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The standard library type traits, such as `std::is_arithmetic`, with one exception (`std::common_type`), are "set in stone". Attempting to specialize them causes undefined behavior. `is_arithmetic` tests if the type is an arithmetic type as defined by the standard; user-defined types are never arithmetic types.

You can write your own trait that tests for support for the arithmetic operators:

```
template<class...> struct voidify { using type = void; };
template<class... Ts> using void_t = typename voidify<Ts...>::type;

template<class T, class = void>
struct supports_arithmetic_operations : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct supports_arithmetic_operations<T, 
           void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>()),
                  decltype(std::declval<T>() - std::declval<T>()),
                  decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<T>()),
                  decltype(std::declval<T>() / std::declval<T>())>> 
       : std::true_type {};
```

The partial specialization will match only if all four expressions are well-formed (i.e., that `T` supports operators `+, -, *, /`).

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84f92e90f9437a78).

Comment: While being cool (really), it doesn't fail on Visual Studio 2013... :(  Any idea?

Comment: @xtofl VC++ doesn't support expression SFINAE, on which this depends.

Comment: Would attempting to obtain the address of those operators also work, or does that run into other problems? My guess would be that even if that does work, it would be the less favorable option due to the function pointer casts that would be required to overcome the ambiguity issue. But I'm not sure if that's the only thing that could hinder that approach.

Answer (score 3):

`std::is_arithmetic<T>::value` is by definition only `true` if `T` is arithmetic type in terms of C++ standard, which is integral or floating type, which in turn are fundamental types only:

> Types `bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called *integral types*.
>
> There are three *floating point* types: `float`, `double`, and `long double`.