# numeric_limits is wrong on a BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF

Tags: c++, boost, numeric-limits

I was supposing that numeric_limits::max() on a BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF defined type would give the same result than on the underlying type. But the following program shows that it is not the case (compiled with g++ or clang++ with boost 1.65):

```
#include <boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(uint64_t, s);

int main(int , char **)
{
  std::cerr << std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() << std::endl 
            << std::numeric_limits<s>::max() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp
$ ./a.out
18446744073709551615
0
```

Is it the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was supposing that numeric_limits::max() on a BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF defined type would give the same result than on the underlying type.

There's no reason to suppose that.

You've literally asked for a new type. That's what it means to have a *strong* typedef. That's why you used `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` instead of, well, `typedef`.

`std::numeric_limits` does not, cannot, and should not provide meaningful information for types of which it is unaware, like the new ones you've created.

Comment: It's still counter-intuitive that `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` do not define a specialization for the type it generated, isn't it?

Comment: @Bob__ not *all* the functions (that would indeed defeat the purpose of a strong typedef), but `std::numeric_limits` specifically.

Comment: @Quentin, this new type may have different semantics, and the default specialization of `numeric_limits` may be wrong. Suppose I want to define `my_int` with the range `-100..100` and I use `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, my_int)` to this aim. Then it is reasonable to expect that `numeric_limits<my_int>::max()`, if defined, returns `100`, not `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @Quentin better fail obviously rather than getting wrong results silently

Comment: I agree with Quentin, my (obviously wrong) expectation was that the new type would reproduce exactly the behavior of the inherited type. And it does of addition for example. But not when instantiating the numeric_limits template. @Evg, for me BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF was just renaming the type, not adding features like in your example.

Comment: @Kleag, that what `typedef` and `using` are for. They introduce a new name, but not a new type.

Comment: Yes, I know. I saw the strong typedef like a way to have a new type that avoids the wrong use of wrong types. But I was expecting some magic for templates like std::numeric_limits to behave intuitively.
OK. I was wrong. I am disappointed. I'm now checking my code base for wrong uses of this construct.

Comment: I'd say it's very unfortunate that `std::numeric_limits<s>::max()` even compiles...

Comment: @Evg, yes, a compilation failure would avoid the propagation of such errors.

Comment: @Kleag, I made a comment in the form of an answer about why this code compiles.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica, I'm sorry. =)

Answer (score 1):

Your expectations are wrong. In a sense the effect you see is exactly what a strong typedef is made for. Your `s` is not `int` but a seperate type. `std::numeric_limits` cannot possibly know about your type, hence as with any other custom type you would have to provide your own specialization to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment.

I was thinking about why `std::numeric_limits<s>::max()` doesn't fail to compile and why it returns (or rather, prints) `0`. When I was preparing a new question, I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520847/c-why-does-numeric-limits-work-on-types-it-does-not-know).

So this is what happens. `std::numeric_limits<s>` is not specialized for `s` [*], but the primary template `std::numeric_limits<T>` is defined with some member functions, `max()` among them, returning certain default values. In particular, `max()` returns the default-constructed `T{}`. So, `std::numeric_limits<s>::max()` returns `s{}`.

`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(uint64_t, s)` defines a `struct` with a single data member and a user-defined conversion `operator uint64_t()`. The presence of this operator makes the code like this `std::cerr << std::numeric_limits<s>::max()` work: `s{}` converts into `uint64_t(0)`.

[*] `static_assert(!std::numeric_limits<s>::is_specialized)`